# Daemon Flow unable to access OneDrive.DriveItem.Content - how to allow daemon flow to access all user's OneDrive for Business data?

Tags: c#, azure, daemon, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am coding against the `Microsoft Graph CSharp SDK` and have implemented a [Daemon or Server Application to Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api). The daemon calls a web API, built on OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant type.

I am then creating calls to access specific user's `DriveItem` `Stream`.

*My Request call:*

```
var driveItemSteam = await graphServiceClient.Drives["test@test.onmicrosoft.com"].Items["01MPVS7H3LTYVLJEAP5ZG2XOZ5EGHI5I4R"].Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

My question is if there is a way for a daemon application to access a user's `Content`. Is there something that I am missing from my request call to allow an `App` level permission to access a specific user's OneDrive for business `DriveItem`?

Comment: Microsoft Graph doesn't yet support app-only scenarios with files. As you have noted, you'll see an error trying to download files from the API when using app-only authentication. Consider adding / voting on adding this via our UserVoice page: https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/category/89523-developer

Comment: @RyanGregg I am assuming that if I tried to access the `Microsoft.Graph.downloadUrl` that this would not work either?

Comment: That's right. The download URLs don't work for app-only access. You can use Microsoft Graph up until that point, although a few other parts of the API also don't work in app-only mode right now. We're working on fixing those issues so we can officially support this authentication style, but I don't have an ETA.

Comment: You can fall back to using the SharePoint REST API directly when you want to download file, as I've done in this older example: https://github.com/rgregg/onedrive-app-delegate-sample. However, that requires you to get a new access_token for the SharePoint endpoint.

Comment: @RyanGregg I'm trying something similar, but using Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant so I use user credentiails, not just app-only access, but I can't get file access that way. Is that not supported either? (See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43885966/177018)