# How to completely automate oauth2 code/token generation in for Microsoft Graph?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access Microsft Graph APIs and I need to automate the process of oauth. I do not want to have a web app in order to sign on microsoft login page to obtain code and token. Is there a way to acheive this in backend where I can login from the python script itself  ?

I've tried this resource- https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-auth but here the login to microsoft is done on the UI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to authorize service to use Microsoft Graph user account without user interaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885966/how-to-authorize-service-to-use-microsoft-graph-user-account-without-user-intera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible (to a degree) depending on your use case.

It's described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

Step 3 may be done in Azure portal when creating the application.

The above will allow you to create oauth tokens programmatically (once step 3 is done).